# How to handle script timeout error in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

In my Classic ASP application I am trying to generate a web report having more than 7K and 14K records respectively, but it shows "Script TimeOut" error after 10 to 15 minutes.

The IIS setting is already more than default value.And also I have written the following code in individual page:

```
<% server.scriptimeout=4000 %>
```

Please suggest me how to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

You simply cannot create an app that has HTTP requests that hang by a thread for 15 minutes.  It's just destined for failure no matter what.  You should allow people to request a report, generate it in the background and notify the user the report is still in progress/ready by either email and/or queue.

To even support this you'd need to edit the user's registry:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813827

It's just not a good design.

Answer (score -1):

```
<% server.scriptimeout=4000 %>
```

It is very high timeout.  You should reduce it. A 180 timeout is sufficient because minimum time out is 90 seconds. I hope this solve your problem now.

Comment: The original question asks how to handle a script timing out even with that high value. Suggesting they lower the value, while potentially useful, doesn't answer the question. (If this *does* answer the question, maybe you should provide more detail about how.)