# How to handle: "Script timed out"

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm thinking on how I can handle script time out. 
I wanted to execute a separate function when script time out occurs.

exact scenario:
When the script time out occurs, I want to delete an item in the database.

and by the way, I am using ASP Classic.

Help please.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822860/how-to-handle-script-timeout-error-in-classic-asp

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200028/error-handling-in-classic-asp-without-timeout-error

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like bad design than anything else, IMHO - remember you're dealing with a web page, not a spread sheet or Access database.  If you're generating a report then you have to consider what is actually readable and what sinks into the information overload category.

If you're having problems rendering the page then you could consider the [`GetString` of the `RecordSet` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a very fast and useful function.